# Treeview selection asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, treeview

I have a treeview which loads data from a database to show categories and subcategories for products.
There are 4 levels of categories in the treeview.
I want when the user click an item to show in a grid all the products that in these categories and subcategories (the selected)
This is the code

```
      FilePath = "moneyfest.mdb"

    Dim CNnwind As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & FilePath & ";Persist Security Info=False") '<==== CHANGE HERE 
    Dim DAdtCat As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT *  FROM Categories ", CNnwind)
    Dim DAdSub1 As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM ProductSubCategories where ParentCategory in (select CategoryID from Categories )", CNnwind)
    Dim DAdSub2 As New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * FROM ProductSubCategories2 where ParentCategory in (SELECT id FROM ProductSubCategories where id in (select CategoryID from categories ))", CNnwind)
    Dim DAdSub3 As New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * FROM ProductSubCategories3 where ParentCategory in (SELECT id FROM ProductSubCategories2 where ParentCategory in (SELECT id FROM ProductSubCategories where ParentCategory in (select CategoryID from categories )))", CNnwind)

    DSNWind = New DataSet()
    CNnwind.Open()
    DAdtCat.Fill(DSNWind, "dtCat")
    DAdSub1.Fill(DSNWind, "dtSub1")
    DAdSub2.Fill(DSNWind, "dtSub2")
    DAdSub3.Fill(DSNWind, "dtSub3")
    CNnwind.Close()

    'Create a data relation object to facilitate the relationship between the Customers and Orders data tables.
    DSNWind.Relations.Add("CustToOrd", DSNWind.Tables("dtCat").Columns("CategoryID"), DSNWind.Tables("dtSub1").Columns("ParentCategory"))
    DSNWind.Relations.Add("OrdToDet", DSNWind.Tables("dtSub1").Columns("id"), DSNWind.Tables("dtSub2").Columns("ParentCategory"))
    DSNWind.Relations.Add("OrdToDetDet", DSNWind.Tables("dtSub2").Columns("id"), DSNWind.Tables("dtSub3").Columns("ParentCategory"))
    '''''''''''''''''''''''
    TreeView2.Nodes.Clear()
    Dim i, n As Integer
    Dim parentrow As DataRow
    Dim ParentTable As DataTable
    ParentTable = DSNWind.Tables("dtCat")

    For Each parentrow In ParentTable.Rows
        Dim parentnode As TreeNode
        parentnode = New TreeNode(parentrow.Item(1))
        TreeView2.Nodes.Add(parentnode)
        ''''populate child'''''
        '''''''''''''''''''''''
        Dim childrow As DataRow
        Dim childnode As TreeNode
        childnode = New TreeNode()
        For Each childrow In parentrow.GetChildRows("CustToOrd")
            childnode = parentnode.Nodes.Add(childrow(1))
            childnode.Tag = childrow("SubCategoryName")
            ''''populate child2''''
            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            Dim childrow2 As DataRow
            Dim childnode2 As TreeNode
            Dim childrow3 As DataRow
            Dim childnode3 As TreeNode
            childnode2 = New TreeNode()
            For Each childrow2 In childrow.GetChildRows("OrdToDet")
                childnode2 = childnode.Nodes.Add(childrow2(1))
                childnode3 = New TreeNode()
                For Each childrow3 In childrow2.GetChildRows("OrdToDetDet")
                    childnode3 = childnode2.Nodes.Add(childrow3(1))

                Next childrow3
            Next childrow2
            ''''''''''''''''''''''''

        Next childrow
        '''''''''''''''
    Next parentrow
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Do you want someone to write an ASP.NET application to render your code?

Comment: Maybe my English is not so good but I'm already wrote the code as you see. My question is how and if its possible to take the category id and the subcategory id of the selected node, so I can make a query to find the related products.